# How can I force SSIS to treat a named range as rows vs columns?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have spreadsheets with named ranges in them I would like to upload to SQL Server as part of a monthly process. The named ranges happen to go across columns in excel, but are ultimately rows of data in SQL server. Is there a way to force the connector to treat that named range as rows vs columns, as I am running into a 255 column limit otherwise. Something in the connector tells it to treat one named range differently from the other. I am looking for options to force it to treat the excel data as rows.

I am using Excel 2013, SQL Server 2014, Windows 7 Pro and developing using MS Visual Studio 2015

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using VS, maybe you should create a program to read your excel, and then insert the rows into SQL. Schedule the new program as a scheduled task that runs monthly.

Comment: Chuck thanks for the feedback. I used to use DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet to bring the data in from excel into SQL2014 through an automated process. This worked great until I hit a limit of 255 columns. The columns are actually imported as rows of data into SQL, it's just that for ease of use for the excel end user the data in the spreadsheet appears across columns not down rows of cells. This brought me to consider SSIS but it seems to have the same limitations with columns. So I am looking for a way to leave the spreadsheet the way it is yet have the data come in as rows.

Comment: Cool, that would be better anyway, much easier to read going down.